# When is a number even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why does something like $a^2 = 2b^2$, show that $a^2$ and thus $a$ are even numbers?

My feeling is that it's because one can divide $a^2$ by two and hence it must be even.

Can anybody give me a clear explanation as to why $a$ is even (in this case) more specifically? Is there mathematical proof?

Comment: You're right that $a^2$ is even because you can divide it by two. That's the very definition of "even."

Comment: Shouldn't be added $a$ and $b$ are integer (or even natural)...? I know it follows from the domain given by a tag (elementary number theory), however the tag is below the text and can be easily overlooked.

Comment: @CiaPan -- $a$ and $b$ can not *both* be integers unless $a=b=0$. Thus, the unstated assumption -- which should definitely be made explicit -- is that $a$ and $b^2$ are integers.

Comment: @Mico If $a$ is not integer then it makes no sense to talk about $a^2$ and $a$ being *even*. If $b$ isn't integer it makes no sense to conclude about $a$ being even or not based on $b^2$ being *doubled*.

Comment: @CiaPan - Given the setup, the only possible integer value for $b$ is $b=0$ -- in which case $a=a^2=0$ as well. (See also Lawrence's answer.) What's required is that $b^2$ be an integer, which implies that $a^2=2b^2$ is an integer. (The notation "$b^2$" is a distraction; it would be better if the problem were stated as $a^2=2c$ for non-negative integers $a$ and $c$.) Naturally, $a^2$ being an integer does not guarantee that $a$ is an integer. Hence the additional requirement that $a$ be an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key observation is that odd $\times$ odd $=$ odd.

Now, $a^2=2b^2$ implies that $a^2$ is even. If $a$ were odd, then $a^2=a\cdot a$ would be odd. Hence $a$ is even.

Comment: Yes, but why does a^2 = 2b^2 imply that a^2 is even in the first place?

Comment: @LostAce, because $a^2$ is $2$ times something. What is your definition of *even*?

Comment: @LostAce: If $x=2y$ and $y$ is an integer, then $x$ is an even integer.  What is *your* definition of *even*?

Comment: @LostAce note that what Ihf said is only true if the "something" is an integer.

Answer (score 9):

The multiple-of-2 reason has been raised by a number of others.

Interestingly, $a^2 = 2b^2$ has no integer solution other than $a=b=0$.

The form arises from a proof that $\sqrt 2$ is not rational. That is, $\not \exists a,b \in Z : \sqrt 2 = {a \over b}$. Squaring both sides gives you the equation you started with. The proof starts with assuming that $a,b$ are co-prime. As others have observed, $a^2$ is even, hence $a$ is even. So $a^2$ is a multiple of $4$, making $b$ even, contradicting the co-prime assumption.

Comment: The idea that something is even because it is always zero is kinda funny. +1 for the alternative answer.

Comment: Nice that you mentioned this. I would like to stress, though, that this proof uses the parity of $a$ to imply that it must be $0$, not vice-versa, i.e. @MaartenBodewes's comment is backwards. (I'm not taking it too seriously, just pointing this out for the benefit of other readers)

Comment: @A.P. Thanks. Treat the $\sqrt 2$ comment as an aside. I edited my answer when I noticed the circular argument otherwise. Note that $a=b=0$ is not a solution to the proof of $\sqrt 2$ irrationality, but the irrationality argument proves there are no other solutions to the OP's equation. I didn't include the parity proof as it had already been presented many times on this page by the time I answered. On a lighter note, since the parity argument only shows no other solutions exist and implicitly excludes $a=0$, the constructive reason $a$ is even turns out to be due to $a=0$, not parity :) .

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for noticing :) .

Answer (score 2):

By definition a number $x$ is even if there exists an integer $y$ such that $x = 2y$. For your case you have $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$. This is why $a^2$ is even. You can further deduce that $a$ is even from here if you choose.

Answer (score 2):

You are given:$$a^2=2b^2$$This implies that $a^2$ is equal to **two** times some number.

If you multiply **any** integer by $2$ then you will get an **even** number.

We can therefore conclude that $a^2$ must be **even**.

Next we observe that the only way to get an **even** integer after squaring is to start off with an **even** integer.

In other words: **even** times **even** = **even**

Where as: **odd** times **odd** = **odd**

We can therefore conclude that since $a^2$ is **even** then this implies that $a$ must also be **even**.

Comment: "If you multiply any number by 2 then you will get an even number." Not if you multiply 1.5 by 2...

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - corrected my descriptions to say "integer" instead of "number"

Answer (score 2):

[Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) says that every integer $>1$ can be *uniquely* expressed as a product $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ (for primes $p_i$ and integers $\alpha_i$).

Since you know $a^2=2b^2$, you know that $2$ has to be somewhere in the representation of $a^2$, and thus in the representation of $a$ (raising $a$ to any positive integer power $n>1$ *only* enlarges the $\alpha_i$, not changing the primes $p_i$).

By definition, a number $b$ is even iff $2$ is somewhere in the unique prime-product representation of $b.$

Comment: No, by definition a number is even if it can be written as twice an integer, no uniqueness is needed for this definition.

Answer (score 1):

a and $a^{2}$ have the same parity. if $a$ is even, then $a=2k$ for some integer $k$. hence $a^{2}=4k^{2}$, still even!. And if $a$ is odd, a=2k+1, $a^{2} =4k^{2}+4k+1=2(2k^{2}+2k)+1$ so $a^{2}$ is odd! (it also follows from modlar arithmetic)!

Comment: Oops. Didn't see this. Wasn't trying to copy. :p

Answer (score 1):

$a^2=2b^2$ means $a^2$ is divisible by 2. So I think you want to prove if $a^2$ is even, then $a$ is even. Or we can prove the contrapositive. If $a$ is odd, then $a^2$ is odd. $a=2k+1$ implies $a^2=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1$ which means $a^2$ is also odd.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is odd, so is $a^2$ and so is $2b^2$ !?